# Javascript event handlers

Tags: jquery, events

Don't look  exactly at the code , i will try to write pseudo code , for you just to understand the idea and my problem .  So imagine i have such a function (pay attention to `var name = $('#name').val();` )

```
  function createFolder(button1, button2, element){

    var btns = {};
    btns[button1] = function(){
       var name = $('#name').val();
      .....
      $(this).dialog("close");
    };
    btns[button2] = function(){
      // Do nothing
      $(this).dialog("close");
    };
    $("<form><input type='text' id='name' name='name'/></form>").dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      title: 'Condition',
      modal:true,
      buttons:btns
    });
  }
```

Basically it's jsut a dialogue , which opens as a form and 2 buttons.

Okay so , when DOM loads my plugin activates doing some magic , runs overt tables  `<tr>`  tags  and every `<a>` tag get event handler attached to it . Something like this:

```
function initialize(){
  ...Some magic here...
  .....

  node.find('#action-links').children().on('click',function(e){
     createFolder( node,'Create Folder', 'Cancle' );

  }
  .....
}
```

**What happens is**  that within that createFolder function i call initialize again , and same element  #action+link  gets more than 1 event handler, which gets executed  multiple times when i click  second , third  etc  times .  I deal with it by deleting old event handler. And jquery stop propogation method as far as i tried helps too.

**What i don't understand is why when i get input value in a variable 'name' , first time it gets it beautifully , but when i click second , third etc times i always get value i inserted the first time instead of new value i inserted .  Everything works fine if i don't call  initialize within createFolder  function , and don't assign multiple event handlers.I think  something is wrong with event handlers ... but i am not sure again .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep creating new form elements with the same id.  Since ids should be unique, it seems to be referencing only the first element that you create.  Instead of creating the form over and over again, the last part of your `createFolder` function should be something like:

```
if (!$('#form-name').length) {
    $('body').append($("<form id='form-name'><input type='text' id='name' name='name'/></form>"))
}
$("#form-name").dialog({
    // etc
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. That makes sense , i didn't know that it creates everytime new form.